# How to turn on GPU Emulation for Android 4 on Ubuntu Natty

Tags: android, gpu, ubuntu-11.04, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have written an app which streaming video using HLS streaming to android 4 device (4.0.3). When I test my app on the Android Emulator i get only the audio and the log says GPU emulation   not enabled. So I edited the AVD setting to enable GPU emulation. But when I try to run the app after this, the AVD crashed and the message in Console is like this

```
.
.
.
[2012-01-16 12:56:48 - a] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-01-16 12:56:48 - a] Uploading a.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-01-16 12:56:48 - a] Installing a.apk...
[2012-01-16 12:56:50 - Emulator] emulator-arm: ../../src/xcb_io.c:140: dequeue_pending_request: Assertion `req == dpy->xcb->pending_requests' failed.
[2012-01-16 12:56:51 - a] Success!
[2012-01-16 12:56:51 - a] Failed to install a.apk on device 'emulator-5554': device not found
[2012-01-16 12:56:51 - a] com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: device not found
[2012-01-16 12:56:51 - a] Launch canceled!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the API 15, you can go to your AVD, click Edit, go to Hardware, click the New button, in property search for GPU emulation,and then turn the value to yes, that should enable GPU emulation. See that API 14 and below don't support this feature.